# Image from asset folder - out of memory exception on set image to imageView

Tags: android, android-imageview, out-of-memory, android-assets

I have simple code (adding image to imageView from asset folder):

```
InputStream path = getAssets().open("z1_1.jpg");
Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(path);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bit);
```

When this code execute it throw error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-10 05:24:32.492: E/AndroidRuntime(2303): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

Any sugestions where is the problem?

Comment: How big is the image? You might want to try scaling down the image a bit.

Comment: what are the dimensions of z1_1.jpg ?

Comment: 234KB 1000x700px is this size to big?

Comment: If I scale down to 400x200 and to 19KB work fine but LogCat write log: 04-09 15:51:42.223: D/dalvikvm(1971): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 421K, 6% free 10641K/11271K, paused 106ms

Comment: Is this normal behaviour?